# Using later version of webpack causes JavaScript error in bundle.js file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a react app that uses webpack and when I use the latest version of webpack it causes a javascript error in the bundle.js file. This is the error I am getting:

```
bundle.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Here is a snippet from the bundle.js file.

```
(function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    function hotDisposeChunk(chunkId) {
/******/        delete installedChunks[chunkId];
/******/    }
/******/    var parentHotUpdateCallback = window["webpackHotUpdate"];
/******/    window["webpackHotUpdate"] = 
/******/    function webpackHotUpdateCallback(chunkId, moreModules) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
/******/        hotAddUpdateChunk(chunkId, moreModules);
/******/        if(parentHotUpdateCallback) parentHotUpdateCallback(chunkId, moreModules);
/******/    } ;
```

The error is coming from this line.

```
var parentHotUpdateCallback = window["webpackHotUpdate"];
```

If I go to a lower version of webpack and webpack-dev-server the error goes away but I have to use a newer version because it has support for older browsers.  Here is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "ava",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "broadwayjs": "0.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "query-string": "^5.0.1",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14",
    "react16-spinjs": "^3.0.1",
    "start": "^5.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "dev": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "react-scripts build webpack",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^6.13.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.0"
  }
}
```

Here is my webpack.config.js file.

```
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: {
    portal: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './src/index.js'
    ],
    decoder: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      'broadwayjs/Player/Decoder'
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'assets'),
    filename: '[name]ReactBundle.js',
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      appMountId: 'root',
      chunks: ['portal']
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src',
    hot: true
  },
  module:{
    rules:[
      {
        test:/\.css$/, 
        use: [
          {loader: "style-loader"},
          {loader: "css-loader"}
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/, 
        use: {loader: 'babel-loader'}, 
        exclude: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ]
      },
      {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,         // Match both .js and .jsx files
          use: {loader: "babel-loader"},
          exclude: [
              path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
          ]
      },
      {   test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
          use: {loader: "url-loader?name=src/img/[name].[ext]"}
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your webpack config?

Comment: I added it to the original post.

Comment: I did get the error to go away with this combination of webpack and webpack-dev-server.  It's not the ideal fix but it does work.  "webpack": "3.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.0"

Comment: I have the same issue - did you find any other solution?

Comment: My comment above is still working.  We are only supporting chrome 34 temporarily.

Comment: This happens only with `HotModuleReplacementPlugin`